# Query OS for hardware characteristics of wireless adapters

Tags: linux, wifi, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi with two wireless adapters connected to it – one has an antenna. [WiFi Dongle - Ultra Long Range High Gain w/ 5dBi Antenna](http://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi/accessories/wifi-dongles/wifi-dongle-ultra-long-range-high-gain-w-5dbi-antenna).

I am trying to write a script that queries my Linux box for wireless interfaces, finds out which one is the one that has the antenna connected and put it into hotspot mode. Tomorrow, it can be any other adapter with an antenna attached.

Are there any tools or commands that can help? Any entries in `/proc` or `/sys` that tell me this is the required device?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, /sys/class/net/`interface name` holds the key. If there is a `wireless` directory contained in one of the `interface name` directories, then that is a wireless interface.